# How can I get specific rows of data from h2o dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, h2o

I am not able to understand how I can slice the h2o data frame based on particular rows specially with which function. can some one help me please.

Sample code I am trying:

iris_hf <- as.h2o(iris)

iris_hf[h2o.which(iris_hf[, 1] == 4.4),]

Similar login in R code:(reference)

data[which(data$col_1>0 &
              data$col_2 != 0 & data$col_3>0),]

Answer (score 0):

H2o Which function is not same as R which function specially in the above case. So we used subset function.